# Grouping dataframe rows by start/end timestamps

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have an application log I am pulling into a pandas dataframe, parsing various pieces of each event into separate columns, that is similar to this:

```
data1 = {'timestamp': ['01-01-2021 12:00:00','01-01-2021 12:01:00','01-01-2021 12:02:00','01-01-2021 12:03:00','01-01-2021 12:04:00','01-01-2021 12:05:00','01-01-2021 12:06:00','01-01-2021 12:07:00','01-01-2021 12:08:00','01-01-2021 12:09:00','01-01-2021 12:10:00','01-01-2021 12:11:00','01-01-2021 12:12:00','01-01-2021 12:13:00','01-01-2021 12:14:00'],
    'event':     ['start','x','y','start','z','end','x','end','start','x','end','start','q','end','start'],
    'account':   ['bob','bob','bob','jane','bob','bob','jane','jane','todd','todd','todd','bob','bob','bob','ned'] }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
print(df1)

    timestamp            event     account
0   01-01-2021 12:00:00  start     bob
1   01-01-2021 12:01:00      x     bob
2   01-01-2021 12:02:00      y     bob
3   01-01-2021 12:03:00  start    jane
4   01-01-2021 12:04:00      z     bob
5   01-01-2021 12:05:00    end     bob
6   01-01-2021 12:06:00      x    jane
7   01-01-2021 12:07:00    end    jane
8   01-01-2021 12:08:00  start    todd
9   01-01-2021 12:09:00      x    todd
10  01-01-2021 12:10:00    end    todd
11  01-01-2021 12:11:00  start     bob
12  01-01-2021 12:12:00      q     bob
13  01-01-2021 12:13:00    end     bob
14  01-01-2021 12:14:00  start     ned
```

Pretty striaght forward log.  The timestamps are strings but can easily be converted to datetime objects if needed.  The log lists various actions performed by the user, but what I am interested in doing is generating a report of the account sessions by user.  Something like this:

```
     account  start                end
0    bob      01-01-2021 12:00:00  01-01-2021 12:05:00
1    jane     01-01-2021 12:03:00  01-01-2021 12:07:00
2    todd     01-01-2021 12:08:00  01-01-2021 12:10:00
3    bob      01-01-2021 12:11:00  01-01-2021 12:13:00
4    ned      01-01-2021 12:14:00                  NaN
```

It's easy enough to group by start and end times, the problem thing I can't figure out is how to do this when a user has multiple sessions in the time period I am looking at.  In the pseudo log data above Bob has 2 sessions opened, but could in theory have opened 100 sessions depending on the date range of the data I'm looking at.  The application in question does restrict users to 1 session at a time, so I shouldn't see the same account with 2 sessions open at the same time.

How do I group the session start/end times together into 2 columns like this by account when the account could have multiple sessions in the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could identify the starts and use `pivot_table`:

```
(df1.assign(idx=df1['event'].eq('start').groupby(df1['account']).cumsum())
    .pivot_table(index=['account', 'idx'], columns='event', values='timestamp', aggfunc='first')
    [['start', 'end']]
 )
```

Output:

```
event                      start                  end
account idx                                          
bob     1    01-01-2021 12:00:00  01-01-2021 12:05:00
        2    01-01-2021 12:11:00  01-01-2021 12:13:00
jane    1    01-01-2021 12:03:00  01-01-2021 12:07:00
ned     1    01-01-2021 12:14:00                  NaN
todd    1    01-01-2021 12:08:00  01-01-2021 12:10:00
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
(df1.assign(idx=df1.event.eq('start').groupby(df1.account).cumsum())  # enumerate the `start` event by account
    .loc[lambda x: x['event'].isin(['start','end'])]                  # only keep `start` and `end` events
    .set_index(['idx','account','event'])                             # set index and unstack
    ['timestamp'].unstack()                               # then unstack
    .reset_index(level=1).reset_index(drop=True)          # tidying up
)
```

Output:

```
event account                  end                start
0         bob  01-01-2021 12:05:00  01-01-2021 12:00:00
1        jane  01-01-2021 12:07:00  01-01-2021 12:03:00
2         ned                  NaN  01-01-2021 12:14:00
3        todd  01-01-2021 12:10:00  01-01-2021 12:08:00
4         bob  01-01-2021 12:13:00  01-01-2021 12:11:00
```